# Refresh page after submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit, page-refresh

I have a website that adds markers to a map according to a form submission. After submitting the form, the marker does not show up until the user refreshes the page. Therefore, I am trying to make it so that, upon hitting submit, the page automatically refreshes. There are many questions like this but all include php and I am not sure how to apply them to my code. Here is what I have currently:

(1) when submitting form js file

```js
function mainController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.formData = {};

  $http.get('/api/events')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.events = data;
      initMap(data);
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        console.log(data[i].eventLocation);
      }
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });

  // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
  $scope.createEvent = function() {
    $http.post('/api/events', $scope.formData)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
        $scope.events = data;
        console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
      });
  };

  $scope.validateForm = function() { 
    if (!$scope.formData.eventName) {
      alert("Please give your event a name!");
      return false;
    }
    else if (!$scope.formData.eventType) {
      alert("Please choose an event type!");
      return false;
    }
    else if (!$scope.formData.eventLocation) {
      alert("Please choose a location!");
      return false;
    }
    else if (!$scope.formData.eventDetails) {
      alert("Please include some details about your event!");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

(2) My form html file

```html
<!-- Event form -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <!-- Validate form -->
              <form name="myForm" ng-submit="validateForm()">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Event Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="inputName" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.eventName" placeholder="Event name">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Type</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="inputType" ng-model="formData.eventType">
                     <option>Option 1</option>
                     <option>Option 2</option>
                     <option>Option 3</option>
                   </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Location</label>
                   <select class="form-control" id="inputLocation" ng-model="formData.eventLocation">
                     <option>Location 1</option>
                     <option>Location 2</option>
                     <option>Location 3</option>
                   </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Event Details</label>
                   <textarea class="form-control" name="inputDetails" ng-model="formData.eventDetails" rows="2" placeholder="Add details about your event"></textarea>
                 </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <button id="add-event"type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="createEvent()">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: Why are you using Ajax instead of a regular form submission? The whole point of Ajax is to avoid loading a new page.

Comment: window.location = window.location.href

Comment: @Quentin could you give a suggestion on how to simply reload the google map?

Answer (score 0):

@MasNotsram 's answer was correct. In the controller of my HTML file I added the line window location, I added the following line after the function that handled posting pins to a map.

```js
location.href = "http://__DESIRED_WEB_PAGE_REFRESH__";
```

Here is what the controller ended up looking like:

```js
function mainController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.formData = {};

  $http.get('/api/events')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.events = data;
      initMap(data);
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        console.log(data[i].eventLocation);
        //placeMarker(data[i]);
        //test(data);
      }
      //placeMarker(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });

  // when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
  $scope.createEvent = function() {
    $http.post('/api/events', $scope.formData)
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.formData = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
        $scope.events = data;
        console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);

      });
      // SOLUTION LINE
      location.href = "http://__DESIRED_WEB_PAGE_REFRESH__";
  };

  $scope.validateForm = function() { 
    if (!$scope.formData.eventName) {
      alert("Please give your event a name!");
      return false;
    }
    else if (!$scope.formData.eventType) {
      alert("Please choose an event type!");
      return false;
    }
    else if (!$scope.formData.eventLocation) {
      alert("Please choose a location!");
      return false;
    }
    else if (!$scope.formData.eventDetails) {
      alert("Please include some details about your event!");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```